# XML Request - getElementsByTagName nog a function?

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently using this code to read a XML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (true) {
    myFunction(xhttp);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "../wp-content/uploads/2015/12/zuiderspel.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml){
console.log(xml.response);
var x, i, xmlDoc, table;
xmlDoc = xml.response;
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0];
    console.log(x);
}
loadDoc();
</script>
```

(By the way, I have to put 4 spaces in front of each line in Stackoverflow to get it in a codeblock, which is tedious and ruins the indents. How can I do this easier?)

My question: I get the error 
(index):168 Uncaught TypeError: xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Why is this? Using the example found at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_xml this should be right, yet, it's not..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The example says `xmlDoc = xml.responseXML` while you are saying `xmlDoc = xml.response`.